# Opening Workspace in R and rename it

Tags: r, workspace

I'm pretty new with R and have a basic issue.

I am trying to open multiple Workspaces in Rstudio to merge them. Unfortunately, every time I'm opening a Workspace, it takes the name "x" (instead of its file's name). Then when I want to open another workspace it overwrites on the previous one and also takes the name "x".

Can anyone help me with this pretty easy issue?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
myvalue1 <- get(load("YourWorkspace1.RData"))
myvalue2 <- get(load("YourWorkspace2.RData"))
```

So that if `YourWorkspace1` and `YourWorkspace2` contains a variable that has the same name, `myvalue1` will take the value of your variable stored in `YourWorkspace1` and same for `myvalue2`.

But if the workspace you want to save only contains one variable, I suggest you store it using `saveRDS`:

```
saveRDS(x, file = "x.rds")
```

And then load it like that :

```
myvalue <- readRDS("x.rds")
```

I hope this is clear.